# Angular: How to show icon.png depending on the attribute of a item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-hide

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Steve", "hourly_wage":16, "status":"part-time"},
{"name":"Maria", "hourly_wage":25, "status":"full-time"},
{"name":"Jose", "hourly_wage":21, "status":"former"}]
```

I want to display an icon for each person's employment status. A full circle for full time, a half circle for part time and an empty circle for former. How can I go about doing this in Javascript/Angular? I'm thinking an if statement of some sort inside ng-hide?

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Show us what you come up with in a jsfiddle and I'm sure you'll get a better response.

Comment: You might want to use [glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/) for ease of use. Some of them are included in bootstrap and could be displayed by only adding the relevant class to your element (so, using ng-class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most generic way in my opinion would be to create a mapping, then use it.

JS:

```
$scope.statusIconMapping = {"part-time": "half_circle.jpg", 
    "full-time": "full_circle.jpg", 
    "former": "empty_circle.jpg"
};
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    ...
    <img src="{{statusIconMapping[employee.status]}}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you import those icons. Are they images ? Fonts ?
Something like the following should work, assuming that you use images and that they are named part-time.jpg, full-time.jpg, former.jpg and are alle placed in some /resources folder

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in list">
    <img ng-src="/resources/{{obj.status}}.jpg"/>
    {{obj.name}}
</div>
```

this works accordingly for fonts, etc. as well

Answer (score 0):

You should use the status property as your condition, and in your html do something similar to:

```
<div ng-src="/images/icons/{{ status }}.png"></div>
```

...which would come out to `<div src="/images/icons/part-time.png"></div>` or whatever it matches to.

Make sure to use `ng-src`, not `src`, as you will come across problems where the page loads before the AngularJS is rendered and the browser will look for a file with that name of `{{ foo }}` which won't exist of course.

Also, refrain from the extraneous logic as some others showed (with all due respect). Just add another property to your JSON and show an icon based on their status. For example if status is full-time, icon can be 'full-circle.png' in the JSON, or you can just use the status as the name of the icon to keep things even simpler.

For example:

```
{
   status: 'full-time', icon: 'full-circle.png'
}
```

Or even:

```
{
   status: 'full-time'
}
```

And then name your icon `full-time.png` so you can easily use it in the HTML without extra logic or properties.